# Creating Application To Hold Photos and Videos

Tags: mysql, database, facebook, image, video

So if I were to developer a simple application that would store a user's photos and videos, how should I store them. I was thinking of using a cloud service like amazon to store photos/videos and store their urls in a mySQL database. But I was wondering if there are any other better approaches? What does Facebook/Instagram do?

Comment: Unfortunately this type of question doesn't fit on StackOverflow, as you'll only get opinions, with no single right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will attract subjective answers but if you want to use cloud services, you can definitely store the actual photos/videos on the cloud itself. And as you mentioned just store the link the database

The word you might want to research is CDN, Amazon has one service called Amazon S3

Edit, quick Google showed that Instagram is using Amazon S3. You can read [here](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/13649370142/what-powers-instagram-hundreds-of-instances)

Comment: This is a good *opinion* but it's not an answer (with your opinion being Amazon S3). Lots of clouds, lots of opinions, lots of options within each cloud. There's simply no single right answer.

Comment: I agree with David, Amazon S3 is not the only answer/opinion. I am sorry if my answer/opinioni sounds like one